# GCP Data Fusion Twitter Tweet Stream Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, twitter, spark-streaming, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to stream twitter data into a Big Query table using GCP Data Fusion. I've added my twitter credentials to the twitter component and validate with no errors. I also validate the Big Query component with no errors. When I run the preview it stops after around 30 seconds and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
```

Here is an image of my Data Fusion job

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

12/15/2020:
[Adding some basic information about my Data Fusion Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbwoN.png)

Logs:
https://pastebin.com/PxKpqfCp

Comment: Hello @John Grieco, What is your current Data Fusion instance version? Can you share the full Java stack trace that might help evaluating the error?

Comment: @Nick_Kh I've added some basic information about my Data Fusion Instance. Let me know if this helps or if you need more. Thanks!

Comment: Have you switched pipeline mode from batch processing to realtime?  From the error stack trace I saw that problem occurred with launching Spark Streaming engine. Its strange that I'm not able to find Twitter plugin throughout the batch source plugins, furthermore the plugin name is showing Twitter Tweet Stream in realtime mode with the same developer edition instance version.

Comment: @Nick_Kh Yes, the pipeline mode is realtime. I am unable to add the Twitter component without being in realtime mode. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be well known to developers issue, looking through the CDAP issue [tracker](https://cdap.atlassian.net/secure/BrowseProjects.jspa), I've found the relevant thread [PLUGIN-194](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/PLUGIN-194) describing the same problem in particular affecting *Twitter Tweet Stream* plugin functionality. Let's track out this case for any further updates occurred.